# Polymorphism using an interface in go depends on URI path in gin

Tags: go

Go newbie here

I want to build a REST API application using gin for example to create databases
In this app, I want to run different functions depends on my URI path

I know that I can do it like this:

```
router.GET("/db/mysql", mysqlCreate)
router.GET("/db/mariadb", mariadbCreate)
```

My goal to make it work using polymorphism and interface like on this code example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Request struct {
    Name    string
    Version string
}

type mysql struct {
    Request
}

type mariadb struct {
    Request
}

func (p mysql) create() {
    fmt.Println(p.Name, p.Version, " MYSQL")
}

func (sa mariadb) create() {
    fmt.Println(sa.Name, sa.Version, " MARIA")
}

type database interface {
    create()
}

func createDB(h database) {
    h.create()
}

func main() {

    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/db/:service", dbCreate)

    router.Run()

}

func dbCreate(c *gin.Context) {

    // mysql
    serviceName := c.Params.ByName("service")

    var request Request
    // p1 := mysql{
    //  Request{
    //      "test1",
    //      "8.0",
    //  },
    // }
    p1 := serviceName{ //??
        Request{
            "test1",
            "8.0",
        },
    }
    createDB(p1)
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, request)
}
```

I tried different things with type assertion but I can't assign type from the string value like on this example:

```
type services struct {
    mysql
    mariadb
}

type mysql struct {
}

type mariadb struct {
}

serviceName := "mysql"

var svc services

// service,_ := reflect.ValueOf(svc).FieldByName(serviceName).Interface().(mysql)
service,_ := reflect.ValueOf(svc).FieldByName(serviceName).Interface().(serviceName)
```

Is it possible to do it in golang this way? or in another way which I know nothing about)

Comment: If you are a beginner to Go, avoid reflect as much as possible.  It's not needed nearly as much as you may think, and should be reserved for special cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a registry pattern:

```
package dbpkg

var Databases = map[string]func() database {}


func dbCreate(c *gin.Context) {
   serviceName := c.Params.ByName("service")
   db:=Databases[serviceName]()
   // Handle errors
   // work with db
 }
```

Register functions to create instances of services:

```
package mysqldb

type MySQL struct {...}

func init() {
   dbpkg.Databases["mysql"]=func() dbpkg.database {return &MySQL{}}
}
...
```

Comment: Hi Burak, I'm trying to do it in one package and it works perfectly
but when I'm trying to do it like on your example, I see that Database variable is nil and that init() did not ran how I should initialize that mysqldb package in dbpkg?

Comment: Seems like I found the way, just add dbpkg to import in main package with underscore like this:
import _ github.com/user/dbpkg